# Loading data from nested NSUSERDEFAULTS into UITABLEVIEW

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have a DetailViewController which is saving some Data to NSUserDefaults if the user wants. It is like kind of favorite list. Hier is the structure of  the saved Defaults:

```
List =     {
        0002 =         (
                        {
                Picture = "link to picture.jpg";
                Place = "London";
                Title = "Flat with Balcony";
            }
        );
        0003 =         (
                        {
                Picture = "link to picture.jpg";
                Place = "Duesseldorf";
                Title = "Roof Garden"
            }
        );
    };
```

**in viewDidLoad :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // Save to the Dictionary
    _myDict = [[userdefaults dictionaryRepresentation] objectForKey:@"List"];

    NSLog(@"MYDICT  : %@", _myDict);

    // save only the keys which are 0002 and 0003 etc..
    _keysArray = [_myDict allKeys];

    NSLog(@"keysArray  : %@", _keysArray);


    // Print out the elements in keysArray

    for(NSString *key in _keysArray){
        NSLog(@"key : %@", key);

    }
}
```

and in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [_keysArray count]; // gives 2
}
```

finally in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"favoritesCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    // this doesn't work gives only nothing ( not error) It is just empty

    cell.textLabel.text = [_myDict valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"List.%@",_keysArray[indexPath.row]]];

    //cell.textLabel.text = [_myDict valueForKeyPath:@"List"]; // this gives also nothing just empty

   //How is it possible to reach a value of a key in nested NSUserdefaults

    return cell;
}
```

How is it possible to reach  a key value in nested Nsuserdefaults and use them in UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSArray *dataArray = [_myDict objectForKey:_keysArray[indexPath.row]];
NSDictionary *data = dataArray[0];
cell.textLabel.text = [data objectForKey@"Title"];
```

_myDict is List dictionary that contains two arrays at 0002 and 0003 so you need to first extract the array then get the first object that is your data. now you can access all the data of your object.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[_myDict objectForKey:`[_keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]. That will give you the value of one of the keys which is an array of a dictionary with 3 keys (Title, place and picture).

```
NSArray * keyValue = [_myDict objectForKey:[_keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]:
cell.textLabel.text = [keyValue[0] objectForKey:@"Title"];
//will set the cell text to the Title value.
```

Comment: doesn't work. It gives : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e54300'

Comment: What value do you want to assign to your cell label?

Comment: For the title List->0002->Title : "Flat with Balcony" For subtitle  List->0002->Place : "London " and so on. cell.textLabel.text = [_keysArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] gives 0002 and 0003 as Title. But i want one level deeper in reach Title, Place and Picture.

Comment: Thanks for your help but  it gives Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e284e0'

Comment: Hey thanks but keyValue is NSDictionary.  It doesn't compile.

Comment: My bad, forgive my lack of sleep :), make it an Array. Sorry again for the mislead.